# Rewriting With Charles-Proxy Error Status is -1 instead of 503

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, charles-proxy, rewriting

I am attempting to use Charles-Proxy to test some error flow paths on my angular 1 code and so I am intentionally rewriting some of my api requests with Charles Proxy to 503. In the network tab I am seeing the 503 on the options request however when the $http request goes into it's error handling function it returns a -1 as the error status instead of the 503.

```
$http(requestObject).then(function() {
  //some code that isn't running
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error.status) //logs -1
})
```

My Charles proxy rewrite is hitting and the response status is listed like below.

[image: Charles Proxy Response Status]

You can see the console output below here (removed urls from image)

[image]

When I am not rewriting with Charles it works totally fine and if an error naturally comes up it works appropriately as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might Charles is working as you expected.

The problem is the request has been aborted due to CORS policy. See the following description for the status code "-1" and CORS.

[AngularJS $http returns documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/docs/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns)
[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

According to the AngularJS documentation, "-1" status code is returned from $http library, not from Charles or your api server.

Write additional code to allow CORS for your API server and try the request again.